# Xamarin.Forms ZXing Qr-Code Scanner System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: xamarin.forms, nullreferenceexception, zxing

[image]i'm making a xamarin.forms app with qr-code login. When qr-code is valid its ok user is login , but when it's not ok i got   System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' at the end of   scanPage.OnScanResult. this is my code:

**My properties:**

```
  public Command ScanQrCodeCommand { get; set; }
        public Command LogInCommand { get; set; }
        ZXingScannerPage scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
        public String username;
        public string Username
        {
            get { return username; }
            set
            {
                if (username != value)
                {
                    username = value;

                    SetProperty(ref username, value);
                    OnPropertyChanged("Username");

                }
            }
        }

        public String password;
        public string Password
        {
            get { return password; }
            set
            {
                if (password != value)
                {
                    password = value;

                    SetProperty(ref password, value);
                    OnPropertyChanged("Password");

                }
            }
        }
        public User user;
        public User User
        {
            get { return user; }
            set
            {
                if (user != value)
                {
                    user = value;

                    SetProperty(ref user, value);
                    OnPropertyChanged("User");

                }
            }
        }
        public LoginViewModel()
        {
            ScanQrCodeCommand = new Command(execute: async () => await ExecuteScanQrCodeCommand());
            LogInCommand = new Command(execute: async (user_created) => await ExecuteLogInCommand(user_created));
            User = new User();
            scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
            Username = string.Empty;
            Password = string.Empty;
        }
```

**Task for scanning the code :**

```
        async Task ExecuteScanQrCodeCommand()
        {
            if (IsBusy)
                return;

            IsBusy = true;

            var config = new ProgressDialogConfig()
            .SetTitle("Loading...")
            .SetIsDeterministic(false)
            .SetMaskType(MaskType.Clear);
            UserDialogs.Instance.Progress(config);
            try
            {        
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);

                scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
                {
                    LogInCommand.Execute(result.ToString());
                    scanPage.IsScanning = false;

                    // Pop the page and show the result
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                    {

                        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();

                    });
                };<--- Here i get NullREferenceException
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                string error = ex.Message;
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Sth wrong with the code", "OK");
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
                UserDialogs.Instance.Progress(config).Dispose();
            }
        }
```

**Task for logging:**

```
        async Task ExecuteLogInCommand(object userLog)
        {

            if (IsBusy)
                return;

            IsBusy = true;

            var config = new ProgressDialogConfig()
            .SetTitle("Loading...")
            .SetIsDeterministic(false)
            .SetMaskType(MaskType.Clear);
            UserDialogs.Instance.Progress(config);
            try
            {
                var user_log = userLog as string;
                var pom = user_log.split(" ")
                Username = pom[0];
                Password = pom[1];
                User = await FinansovoPreglediDataStore.GetUserToken(Username , Password );
                if (User != null && User.AccessToken != null)
                {
                    SharedFunctions.SaveAccessToken(User.AccessToken);
                    Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainMenu());
                }
                else if (User.AccessToken is  null)
                {
                    await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("ERROR", "WRONG USER, "OK");
                    Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                string error = ex.Message;
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("ERROR", "STH. WRONG", "OK");
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
                UserDialogs.Instance.Progress(config).Dispose();

            }
        }
```

**My call  to API:**

```
        public async Task<User> GetUserToken(string username, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
                {
                    User user = new User();
                    if (username == null || password == null || !CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
                        return null;
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    HttpContent requestContent = new StringContent("grant_type=password&username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&login_type=" + "login_user", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsync("Token", requestContent);
                    var pom = responseMessage.StatusCode;
                    if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string jsonMessage;
                        using (Stream responseStream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                        {
                            jsonMessage = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                        }
                        user = (User)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonMessage, typeof(User));
                        return user;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    GetToastConfig.GetToastNoInternetConnection();
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                string error = ex.Message;
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I can't find really what is the problem. Which object is null?! Someone have the same problem?

**UPDATE**
I finally found it. For all responses i get ,i make Toast. When user scan wrong user or pass it return badRequest from server , and go in default toast. But i don't know why can make instance of GetToastConfig. In BaseViewModel with dependecy service i define all them and inherite. Maybe there is no page with this AsyncPop to show , someone help?

```
    public class GetStatusCode : BaseViewModel
    {
        public GetStatusCode() { }      
        public async void GetResponseCode(int status_code)
        {
            switch (status_code)
            {
                case 404:
                    GetToastConfig.GetToastStatus404();
                    break;
                case 401:
                    var user = await FinansovoPreglediDataStore.RefreshToken(SharedFunctions.GetRefreshToken());
                    if (user != null && user.AccessToken != null)
                    {
                        SharedFunctions.SaveAccessToken(user.AccessToken);
                        SharedFunctions.SaveUser(user);
                        SharedFunctions.SaveRefreshToken(user.RefreshToken);
                        SharedFunctions.SaveUserFirmi(user.Firms);
                    }
                    break;
                case 500:
                    GetToastConfig.GetToastStatus500();
                    break;
                default:
                   GetToastConfig.GetToastStatusDefault();<---- Here get NullReferenceException
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Which object is null?" - use the debugger and look at the stack trace to figure this out

Comment: Not showing which is

Comment: Where i can see that?

Comment: Stack Trace is a property on the exception object

Comment: i updated photo u can see?

Comment: your post does not have any images in it

Comment: edited now , sry not updated image

Comment: that is not helpful.  I repeat my earlier suggestion - "use the debugger and look at the stack trace to figure this out".  If you do not know how to use the debugger now is the time to learn.  Step through every line of code until you find the once causing the exception.

Comment: i added in my code where in debugger showing null object

Comment: how to add stack trace in visual studio?

Comment: I'm debugging line by line

Comment: in Call Stack   0xC in System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw C# Annotated Frame